# Styling custom component

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I have this style component

```
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/styles";

const AppStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  textField: {
    width: 200,
    color: red
  }
}));
  
export default AppStyles;
```

and this component

```
import AppStyles from '../AppStyles'

const LoginPage = (props) => {
  .....
  return (
    <Grid 
      justify="center" >
      <Grid className="h-25">
            <TextField
              fullWidth
              id="username"
              className={AppStyles.textField}
            /> 
            .....
export default LoginPage;
```

The problem is that my custom styles was not exported and my textbox don't have a class 'textField ' atribute seted. What I missing?

```
<input 
aria-invalid="false" id="password" name="password" type="password" 
class="MuiOutlinedInput-input MuiInputBase-input css-1t8l2tu-MuiInputBase-input-MuiOutlinedInput-input" value="">
```

Tks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

makeStyles doesn't give you styles immediately, you should call its return value as a function:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => {...});
```

And call it inside the component:

```
const classes = useStyles();
```

Then, you can use `classes.textField` to implement styles.